# Closing a Polymer Dialog from within a Angular2 component

Tags: angular, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I have a paper-dialog tags.page.html

```
<paper-dialog id="test" #tagDialog>
  <h2>Tag Dialog</h2>
  <tags-form [tag]="tagNameRef.value" [formState]="tagsFormState_ | async" (tag_)="onSaveTag($event)"></tags-form>
</paper-dialog>
```

inside there is a Angular2 component `TagsForm`. I want to close the Dialog when the user click on the method `onClose()` of `TagsFrom`.

I did try this but its not working...

```
onClose() {
    let event = new CustomEvent('iron-overlay-canceled',{
        detail:{canceled:false},
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: false
    });
    this.elem.dispatchEvent(event);        
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? I was thinking that dispatching the event should close the modal. Any pointer as to why this is not working and how to get this to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event `iron-overlay-canceled` is fired when the overlay is canceled, but before **it doesn't close dialog**.

```
close: function() {
  this._setCanceled(false);
  this.opened = false;
},
cancel: function(event) {
  var cancelEvent = this.fire('iron-overlay-canceled', event, {cancelable: true});
  if (cancelEvent.defaultPrevented) {
    return;
  }
  this._setCanceled(true);
  this.opened = false;
},
```

([Github source](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-overlay-behavior/blob/master/iron-overlay-behavior.html#L301))

You can subscribe on this event, but if you want to close the dialog then you have to fire `close` or `cancel` method on dialog component.

If you will call `cancel` method then it will fire the mentioned above `iron-overlay-canceled` and close the dialog. `close` method accordingly will just close the dialog.

The easiest way to achieve this would be to use EventEmitter as shown below:

**tags-form.component.ts**

```
@Output() closeDialog = new EventEmitter();
onClose() {
  this.closeDialog.emit()
}
```

**tags.page.html**

```
<paper-dialog id="dialog" #tagDialog>
  <h2>Tag Dialog</h2>
  <tags-form (closeDialog)="tagDialog.close()"></tags-form>
</paper-dialog>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/egSGPkm7I4crA6EUmXu9?p=preview)**